# What is wrong with this batch echo command?

Tags: batch-file

This code doesnt seem to do anything.

```
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) ^& "C:\Users\"^&strUser^&"\AppData\Roaming\turtle\turtle.bat" ^& Chr(34), 0>>run.vbs
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What are the contents of `turtle.bat`?

Comment: it is part of script that creates vbs file

Comment: problem is that it doesnt add anything to the vbs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) ^& "C:\Users\"^&strUser^&"\AppData\Roaming\turtle\turtle.bat" ^& Chr(34), 0 >>run.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 0 immediately preceding redirection is interpreted as the stdin file stream instead of as a string literal. For future reference, 1 is stdin, and 2 is stdout. The digits 3-9 are undefined, but also can cause problems.

SachaDee's solution works fine, although it adds a trailing space to the output.

You can avoid the trailing space by using parentheses, but this requires escaping `)` in the output.

```
(echo WshShell.Run chr(34^) ^& "C:\Users\"^&strUser^&"\AppData\Roaming\turtle\turtle.bat" ^& Chr(34^), 0) >>run.vbs
```

A simpler solution is to move the redirection to the front.

```
>>run.vbs echo WshShell.Run chr(34^) ^& "C:\Users\"^&strUser^&"\AppData\Roaming\turtle\turtle.bat" ^& Chr(34^), 0
```